# Cart API: cart.data.data.cart_amount is not calculated correctly.... I think

Tags: bigcommerce

1. added a product to cart using API price was $29
2. `GET /v3/carts/cartId` saw `cart_amount` was correct
3. changed product price to $100
4. `GET /v3/carts/cartId` saw `cart_amount` was wrong — it did not see that the product price had changed.

Am i doing something wrong. Do you need more info to help me?

```
bc.add_to_cart = (data,next) => {
    let payload = {
        line_items: data.line_items,
        option_selections: data.option_selections,
        gift_certificatesL: null
    }
    return bc_v3.post(`/carts/${data.cartId}/items`, payload).then(data => {
        return data; // data only show initial product cost
    }).catch(next);
};
```

---

## EDIT

below i am posting the results of `GET carts/id` u will see that the lineItem (id: 125) shows the original price, `29.95`. Immediately after getting the cart I did a request to `GET /catalog/products/125` — that one shows the updated price.

#### `GET: carts/${cartId}`

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "15219c6d-51a8-4267-a38c-29fe62a49182",
        "customer_id": 0,
        "email": "",
        "currency": {
            "code": "USD"
        },
        "tax_included": false,
        "base_amount": 409.7,
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "cart_amount": 409.7,
        "coupons": [],
        "line_items": {
            "physical_items": [
                {
                    "id": "d755137f-b09c-4a02-9da6-cab8da1ae332",
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "variant_id": 89,
                    "product_id": 124,
                    "sku": "test_config",
                    "name": "Test Configurable item",
                    "url": "http://fornida.mybigcommerce.com/test-configurable-item/",
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "taxable": true,
                    "image_url": "https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/s-2bihpr2wvz/products/124/images/389/overview-3-lg-c__55453.1534430965.220.290.jpg?c=2",
                    "discounts": [],
                    "coupons": [],
                    "discount_amount": 0,
                    "coupon_amount": 0,
                    "list_price": 115,
                    "sale_price": 115,
                    "extended_list_price": 230,
                    "extended_sale_price": 230,
                    "is_require_shipping": true
                },
                {
                    "id": "eb5695d6-85e5-4b58-891b-a4bd8b48c56e",
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "variant_id": 90,
                    "product_id": 125,
                    "sku": "test_compt_1",
                    "name": "test component 1",
                    "url": "http://fornida.mybigcommerce.com/test-component-1/",
                    "quantity": 6,
                    "taxable": true,
                    "image_url": "https://cdn7.bigcommerce.com/r-03b8fdf5d1037c0feebbcedfd701c709422a962e/themes/ClassicNext/images/ProductDefault.gif",
                    "discounts": [],
                    "coupons": [],
                    "discount_amount": 0,
                    "coupon_amount": 0,
                    "list_price": 29.95,
                    "sale_price": 29.95,
                    "extended_list_price": 179.7,
                    "extended_sale_price": 179.7,
                    "is_require_shipping": true
                }
            ],
            "digital_items": [],
            "gift_certificates": []
        },
        "created_time": "2018-08-23T15:41:10+00:00",
        "updated_time": "2018-08-23T18:57:55+00:00"
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

---

#### GET `/catalog/products/125`

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 125,
        "name": "test component 1",
        "type": "physical",
        "sku": "test_compt_1",
        "description": "<p>Type a description for this product here...</p>",
        "weight": 2,
        "width": 0,
        "depth": 0,
        "height": 0,
        "price": 125,
        "cost_price": 0,
        "retail_price": 0,
        "sale_price": 0,
        "map_price": 0,
        "tax_class_id": 0,
        "product_tax_code": "",
        "calculated_price": 125,
        "categories": [
            23,
            18
        ],
        "brand_id": 0,
        "option_set_id": 38,
        "option_set_display": "right",
        "inventory_level": 0,
        "inventory_warning_level": 0,
        "inventory_tracking": "none",
        "reviews_rating_sum": 0,
        "reviews_count": 0,
        "total_sold": 0,
        "fixed_cost_shipping_price": 0,
        "is_free_shipping": false,
        "is_visible": true,
        "is_featured": false,
        "related_products": [
            -1
        ],
        "warranty": "",
        "bin_picking_number": "",
        "layout_file": "product.html",
        "upc": "",
        "mpn": "",
        "gtin": "",
        "search_keywords": "",
        "availability": "available",
        "availability_description": "",
        "gift_wrapping_options_type": "any",
        "gift_wrapping_options_list": [],
        "sort_order": 0,
        "condition": "New",
        "is_condition_shown": false,
        "order_quantity_minimum": 0,
        "order_quantity_maximum": 0,
        "page_title": "",
        "meta_keywords": [],
        "meta_description": "",
        "date_created": "2018-08-15T13:46:57+00:00",
        "date_modified": "2018-08-23T18:22:52+00:00",
        "view_count": 7,
        "preorder_release_date": null,
        "preorder_message": "",
        "is_preorder_only": false,
        "is_price_hidden": false,
        "price_hidden_label": "",
        "custom_url": {
            "url": "/test-component-1/",
            "is_customized": false
        },
        "base_variant_id": 90,
        "open_graph_type": "product",
        "open_graph_title": "",
        "open_graph_description": "",
        "open_graph_use_meta_description": true,
        "open_graph_use_product_name": true,
        "open_graph_use_image": true
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: How are you changing the product price to 100? By writing to list_price?

Comment: In the admin on the product’s edit page. Normal way

Comment: That is odd--if you make the request from Postman with the same cart ID, does the cart_amount reflect the new product price?

Comment: Line_item looks good. It’s just cart totals. I’ll post the entire response shortly. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Karen! I made some edits to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the price of an item in the control panel or using the API will not change the price in an existing cart. If you create a new cart then the price will reflect the changes that were made.

The original cart where line_item is $25 dollars and tax is included as well to give a cart_amount of 29.12

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "3a4c8e16-e279-4c30-83df-0010f6d54fba",
        "customer_id": 0,
        "email": "",
        "currency": {
            "code": "USD"
        },
        "tax_included": false,
        "base_amount": 25,
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "cart_amount": 29.12,
        "coupons": [],
        "line_items": {
            "physical_items": [
                {
                    "id": "1e08875e-bf6f-4f1f-b8ba-b2e3cee10394",
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "variant_id": 363,
                    "product_id": 192,
                    "sku": "",
                    "name": "Smith Journal 13",
                    "url": "http://{store_hash}}.mybigcommerce.com/all/smith-journal-13/",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "taxable": true,
                    "image_url": "https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-{{store_hash}}/products/192/images/480/smithjournal1_1024x1024__85081__38998.1534344545.330.500.jpg?c=2",
                    "discounts": [],
                    "coupons": [],
                    "discount_amount": 0,
                    "coupon_amount": 0,
                    "list_price": 25,
                    "sale_price": 25,
                    "extended_list_price": 25,
                    "extended_sale_price": 25,
                    "is_require_shipping": true
                }
            ],
            "digital_items": [],
            "gift_certificates": []
        },
        "created_time": "2018-08-24T14:41:17+00:00",
        "updated_time": "2018-08-24T14:41:17+00:00"
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Update the line_item price `/{store_hash}/v3/carts/{cartId}/items/{itemId}`

```
{
    "line_item":
        {
            "list_price": 30,
            "quantity": 1,
            "product_id": 192
        }
}
```

Response - base_amount is now 30, and cart_amount is also updated to 34.96. This only changes the price for the cart and not the product

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "3a4c8e16-e279-4c30-83df-0010f6d54fba",
        "customer_id": 0,
        "email": "",
        "currency": {
            "code": "USD"
        },
        "tax_included": false,
        "base_amount": 30,
        "discount_amount": 0,
        "cart_amount": 34.96,
        "coupons": [],
        "line_items": {
            "physical_items": [
                {
                    "id": "1e08875e-bf6f-4f1f-b8ba-b2e3cee10394",
                    "parent_id": null,
                    "variant_id": 363,
                    "product_id": 192,
                    "sku": "",
                    "name": "Smith Journal 13",
                    "url": "http://{store_hash}.mybigcommerce.com/all/smith-journal-13/",
                    "quantity": 1,
                    "taxable": true,
                    "image_url": "https://cdn8.bigcommerce.com/s-{store_hash}/products/192/images/480/smithjournal1_1024x1024__85081__38998.1534344545.330.500.jpg?c=2",
                    "discounts": [],
                    "coupons": [],
                    "discount_amount": 0,
                    "coupon_amount": 0,
                    "list_price": 30,
                    "sale_price": 30,
                    "extended_list_price": 30,
                    "extended_sale_price": 30,
                    "is_require_shipping": true
                }
            ],
            "digital_items": [],
            "gift_certificates": []
        },
        "created_time": "2018-08-24T14:41:17+00:00",
        "updated_time": "2018-08-24T14:41:17+00:00"
    },
    "meta": {}
}
```

Comment: ur saying i should update the carts' `line_item` price to reflect what is in the catalog? I didnt know that was possible.

Comment: Yes. For existing carts only. If you create a new cart after the price in the catalog is changed, then the new catalog price will be reflected. Under https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v3/#/reference/cart/server-to-server-cart. Currently only updating line_item price and quantity are possible.

Comment: that works! ... being able to change a `line_item`'s price is an exciting option; but i wonder why the cart does not maintain catalog prices automatically like stencil does... ?

Comment: Something has to "touch" the cart before the price will update after being changed in the control panel, whether that's being written to, or the cart being refreshed on the storefront. I think since you are not using the storefront, it's not refreshing the cart data?

Comment: Now I need to get a cart // check if catalog and line items are different // update the differences on the line-item // get the new cart data... I think this should be considered a bug.